# Proving $\overline{(x-\overline x)(y-\overline y)}=\overline{xy}-\overline x \cdot \overline y$

Tags: statistics, regression, means, linear-regression

In ordinary least squares, it can be shown that $\hat\beta_1 = \frac{\sum(x_i-\bar x)(y_i-\bar y)}{\sum (x_i - \bar x)^2}$. I'm trying to prove this. I arrived at $$\hat\beta_1=\frac{\overline{xy}-\overline x\cdot \overline y}{\overline{x^2}-\overline{x}^2}$$

Apparently at this point I need to use that $$\overline{(x-\overline x)(y-\overline y)}=\overline{xy}-\overline x\cdot \overline y$$ but I can't seem to prove this. Even for the simplest case $n=2$, if I directly expand both sides of $\overline{(x-\overline x)(y-\overline y)}=\overline{xy}-\overline x\cdot \overline y$, it gets very messy and confusing. Is there an easy way to prove this?

Also, if I only arrived at $\hat\beta_1=\frac{\overline{xy}-\overline x\cdot \overline y}{\overline{x^2}-\overline{x}^2}$ and didn't know that $\overline{(x-\overline x)(y-\overline y)}=\overline{xy}-\overline x\cdot \overline y$ should be true, is there a way to figure out what to do next?

Comment: Something is strange since the right side of your proposed equation is the difference of two identical expressions, hence $0$.

Comment: You just need to expand the product (xi-x)(yi-y) and then average. It will be simplified

Comment: Hint: first rewrite $\overline{(x-a)(y-b)}$ for constant $a,\,b$.

Comment: Note that the expression for $\hat \beta_1$ you obtained is the one you would use in a computer code (faster - loop over the data only once)

Comment: $$ \overline{(x-\overline x) \cdot(y-\overline y)}
\\= \overline{x \cdot y-\overline x \cdot y -\overline y \cdot x + \overline x  \cdot \overline y}
\\= \overline{x \cdot y}-\overline x  \cdot \overline y -\overline y  \cdot\overline x + \overline x \cdot  \overline y
\\=\overline{xy}-\overline x\cdot \overline y $$